# Objective -C Call back doesnot working with an unfortunate background crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I'm trying to send a call back listener from a completion block. I initiate callback in custom `UIView` & completion block executes from parent viewcontroller (where `UIView` subviewed). Here is the code... (I dont want to use delegate)

Declaration of Call-Back in `ViewController.h`

```
typedef void(^ExportCompletion)(BOOL success, NSURL* url);
@property (nonatomic, copy) ExportCompletion exportBlock;
-(void) exportCompletionBlock:(ExportCompletion)callback;
```

Initialization & Implementation of Call-Back in `ViewController.m`

```
-(void) exportCompletionBlock:(ExportCompletion)callback
{
    if (callback) {
        self.exportBlock = callback;
    }
}
```

Implementation (call) from Completion handler (its also in `ViewController.m`)

```
-(void)blockAlertAppear:(float)progress{
    if(EXPORT_SESSION_COMPLETED!=progress)
        doing something...
    if(EXPORT_SESSION_COMPLETED==progress){
        self.exportBlock(YES, mCompositor.url);
    }
}
```

Call back operation in uicustomview... `CustomUIView.m`

```
-(void) initUIView{
    [(ViewController*)[[self superview] nextResponder] exportCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSURL *url) {
    if (success) {
        doing something...
    }
}];
```

I can use delegate here but I want to use call back. I'm very new with call back. I like to know why **I'm having the crash (its from background - so dont get the reason) & how do I optimize the code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[(ViewController*)[[self superview] nextResponder]` returns nil that might be a reason for crash. But using [[self superview] nextResponder] is not a good practice. Lets try a completion handler. I try to give you an example.

Declaration of Call-Back in `ViewController.h`

```
typedef void(^ExportCompletion)(BOOL success, NSURL* url);
@property (nonatomic, copy) ExportCompletion exportBlock;
```

In your viewcontroller `ViewController.m` no need to assign `exportCompletionBlock` . Just assign when you need it. For an example you have a delegate in your CustomView which is implemented in `ViewController.m`.

In your `CustomUIView.h` add this

```
typedef void(^ExportCompletion)(BOOL success, NSURL* url);

@protocol CustomUIViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) startExport:(ExportCompletion)completionBlock;
@end
```

Call your delegate from your desired event like

In your `CustomUIView.m`

```
- (IBAction)ButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate startExport:^(BOOL success, NSURL *url) {
        if (success) {
            doing something...
        }
    }];
}
```

In your `ViewCOntroller.m` code remain same but with a slide modification a little

**Same as it was**

```
-(void)blockAlertAppear:(float)progress{
    if(EXPORT_SESSION_COMPLETED!=progress)
        doing something...
    if(EXPORT_SESSION_COMPLETED==progress){
        self.exportBlock(YES, mCompositor.url);
    }
}
```

Implement the delegate in `ViewCOntroller.m`

```
- (void) startExport:(ExportCompletion)completionBlock{
    self.exportBlock = completionBlock;
    the thing you want to do...
}
```

This is a way of handling a completion block. I dont know how much it'll help you. It's just a new way to implement your code. & It helps you prevent use of `[[self superview] nextResponder]` view dependence.

Answer (score 1):

Why your last method calls "initUIView" ??? If you init new View , View dont have Superview , before you not added to superview ([viewController.view addsubview:yourView]). I think, if you print  [(ViewController*)[[self superview] nextResponder] in NSLog , you'll see Nil. And it's reason for Crash